# Resetting UiTableView table height causing table to disappear

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have a view with two UILabels, two UITableViews and a UITextView. I am trying to layout the two tables based on what they will display. I can create the initial table dimensions just fine, but when I go to reset the height of the table based on its actual content, the table no longer displays in the view. Code snippet below:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
// code to set up the first two UILabels (one of which is clinic name)
...

//
// Create the address table
//
CGRect addrRect = self.view.bounds ;
CGFloat addrStart = clinicNameRect.origin.y + (clinicNameRect.size.height)*1.5 ;
addrRect.origin.y =  addrStart;
addrRect.size.height -= addrStart ; // setting it to size of rest of view which is not what I want

addressList = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:addrRect style:UITableViewStyleGrouped] ;
[addressList setDataSource:self] ;
[addressList setDelegate:self] ;

[addressList setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight |  
                                 UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth] ;
[addressList setBackgroundColor:clr] ;
[addressList setBackgroundView:nil] ; // no background

[[self view] addSubview:addressList] ; // tried moving this to after with same result

// have the system layout the table, then reset the height to actual size
[addressList layoutIfNeeded];

CGRect newFrame = [addressList frame] ;
newFrame.size.height = [addressList contentSize].height ;

// make the table's frame exactly match its size
[addressList setFrame:newFrame] ;

// go to set up next UITableView...
```

If I take out the call to setFrame: my table appears just fine (but takes too much space on the view). If I leave that call in, the table does not appear at all.

Comment: are you using storyboards/ autolayout?

Comment: `NSStringFromCGRect` would really simplify this code.

Comment: Laying out the view programmatically because I want the second table to move down as the first table grows. When I used a XIB, as the first table grew, it was obscured by the second table. Maybe I was doing something wrong -- still new at this.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the documentation about the difference between `[UIView bounds]` and `[UIView frame]`.

Although changing the origin in `bounds` can be in some specific situations possible, what you really want is to change the `frame`.

Also, both `frame` and `bounds` are animatable properties. Setting a new value starts an animation and if you then access the value, you don't have to get the current value.

Comment: Thanks, newbie mistake. Still figuring all of this out. I changed to using a frame, but my root problem is still there. When I change the size of the UITableView, it disappears from the view. I thought the problem was origin.y, but it is still not redrawing the table. If I remove the code that resizes the table, the table appears right where I want it, but it is too big. When I go to resize it, it disappears altogether. Any ideas?

Comment: @DanNichols Your code is almost impossible to understand, e.g. why are you setting the height of the table to the height of its content?Also setting the frame of the table twice (first in `initWithFrame:` and then using `setBounds:` (or `setFrame:`) seems strange. I recommend you to simplify the code first, maybe you will find the problem then.

Comment: Let me see if I can better explain what I am trying to do (so ignore my code for now). I have a view with two tables in it. I want each table to display its entire set of cells all the time. But, before I create it, I have no way of knowing how big it will be. So, I create a UITableView that takes up the remainder of the screen. Then, by calling layoutIfNeeded: I can determine the actual size of the table. I want to reset the space the table takes up to exactly the space it needs. I want to do the same for the second table so it appears directly below the first table. If there is an easier...

Comment: way to do this, I am all for it. I just don't know how. Thanks for the help!